# CoreData + iCloud Sync timing confusing

Tags: objective-c, core-data, icloud

My question is how to control the timing of CoreData(local database) sync with the iCloud. As I know if I change the local data the iCloud will change  automatically. It is possible that iCloud sync data with local until i m ready to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a kind of two step synching. Your local data is put first into a container for synching and then the container is synched with the iCloud. This is done by an demon system-wide. You cannot control that.

You want to differ between the "local document" and the "cloud document". As mentioned in the comments, this is akin of anti-conceptional. However, there are two strategies to get this. None of them is tested by me.

1. Do not save the changes you have done in memory.
2. Add a local version of the store and migrate between the local version and the synched version using `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` (`NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`).

Both variants have a big disadvantage: If you delay the time to save the (synched) document, potentially the local version and the ubiquitous version run away more and more. This leads potentially to unresolvable conflicts. There *is* a reason that Apple recommends to save the store as soon and as often as possible (= making it public). BTW: Core Data with iCloud synch is no groupware. Do not even try to use it this way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, here is close scenario: i m using version control application and i have changed/added a lot code in my project(image these are the data in my local), but i don't want to commit to the server(iCloud) until i clicked the "commit" button. So i m a little confused about the "timing".

Comment: This is akin of fighting the framework. You do not have a "local document" that is pushed to the "cloud document". There is only the one and only document that is synched via iCloud. I add two possible solutions to my A.

Comment: Great idea! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direkt way to control the timing, but the local - iCloud sync is not performed until the changes of the managed object context are committed via the `save:` method